# Recording the duration a computer has been locked

Tags: windows, gratis, time-management, portable

I'm looking for a software that is able to display the duration for which a computer has been locked. A balloon notification or a small window like in the image below is sufficient.

[image]

Requirements:

- Runs on Windows 7
- Displays a message or a balloon notification with the duration right after unlocking
- Is portable or can be made portable through simple repackaging
- Can be a standalone software, or a script (as long as the corresponding interpreter is batch or also has a portable version, e.g. [Perl](http://www.perl.org/), [AutoHotKey](http://ahkscript.org/) , etc...)
- Free of charge, being open-source is a plus

I have tried writing my own AutoHotKey script to accomplish the task, but I'm unable to make it display the message upon unlocking